# 2 terabyte table to send from DB to DB in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a table with 2 terabyte worth of data and I need to transfer it between two databases on the same server.

The data is in prod so when I use ETL the production gets affected.

It's 40 days of data and my manager suggested to send daily data starting from the last 40 days.

What is the best solution?

Comment: Can you identify data from the past 40 days? What are your requirements? How much data changes over 40 days (10 rows, 1 million rows, all 2TB worth)?

Comment: maybe you can *from external script* trigger daily bunch of data until the end. If your databases are separated instances you may just activate synchro ; in few days all data will be similar on both in that case.